# How to load multiple views on top of the UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

How to load multiple views one after the another once this view is displayed

```
- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{ 
PageOneViewController *viewController = [[[PageOneViewController alloc] init]autorelease];

viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

}
```

Now on top of this viewcontroller how i can load multiple viewcontrollers one after the other.

Please advice.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you want to display it. If you're using a `UINavigationController`, you can do something like:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

or, if you'd like to present it as a modal view, you can do this to support older versions of iOS:

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

or, if you're only targeting iOS 5, do this:

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Then to dismiss the view controller, on older versions of iOS:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

or if you're only targeting iOS 5:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: i have uitoolbar which has mostly uibuttons like play stop and rewind and i want this toolbar to appear in allviews. So how i can use present modalviewcontroller and pushviewcontroller

Comment: Why do you need to swap out an entire view just for play, stop and rewind? If you need to swap out views with a toolbar, you should be using a `UITabBarController`.

Comment: basically when views are loaded one after the other i want user to have the control if in between user wants to pause or stop the audiofile or to get the info about the audiofile that is the reason i want uitoolbat to appear on all the views

Comment: It sounds like you should be using a `UINavigationController`. With a navigation controller you can have a toolbar that appears in all views. However, you'll have to set the toolbar items in each `UIViewController`'s viewDidLoad method. And then you can push new view controllers using `[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];`

Comment: so how i change uitoolbar to uinavigationcontroller

Comment: Make a new project in Xcode using the navigation template and look at how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a UINavigationController. That is a kind of super-controller that can load a stack of other view controllers one after another.